# How to show full output on linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a program that runs and shows a GUI window. It also prints a lot of things on the shell. I need to view the first thing printed and the last thing printed. the problem is that when the program terminates, if I scroll to the top of the window, the stuff printed when it began is removed. So stuff printed during the program is now at the top. So that means I can't view the first thing printed.

Also I tried doing `> out.txt`, but the problem is that the file only gets closed and readable when I manually close the GUI window. If it gets outed to a file, nothing gets printed on the screen and I have no way to know if the program finished. I can't modify any of the code too.

Is there a way I can see the whole list of text printed on the shell?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the output of a program goes to your terminal window, the program generally flushes its output after each newline.  This is why you see the output interactively.

When you redirect the output of the program to `out.txt`, it only flushes its output when its internal buffer is full, which is probably after every 8KiB of output.  This is why you don't see anything in the file right away, and you don't see the last things printed by the program until it exits (and flushes its last, partially-full buffer).

You can trick a program into thinking it's sending its output to a terminal using the `script` command:

```
script -q -f -c myprogram out.txt
```

This `script` command runs `myprogram` connected to a newly-allocated “pseudo-terminal” (or `pty` for short).  This tricks `myprogram` into thinking it's talking to a terminal, so it flushes its output on every newline.  The `script` command copies `myprogram`'s output to your terminal window and to the file `out.txt`.

Note that `script` will write a header line to `out.txt`.  I can't find a way to disable that on my test Linux system.

In the example above, I assumed your program takes no arguments.  If it does, you either need to put the program and arguments in quotes:

```
script -q -f -c 'myprogram arg1 arg2 arg3' out.txt
```

Or put the program command line in a shell script and pass that shell script to the `script` command.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `tee` command to get output/error in a file as well on terminal:

```
your-command |& tee out.log
```

Though just keep in mind that this output is line buffered by default (4k in size).